# How to support MouseUp, MouseDown and MouseMove events regardless of using Mouse or Touch

Tags: c#, wpf, events, touch, mouse

I'm trying to make a WPF application that will support both Mouse and Touch. During development I have been using a Mouse only, but after testing with a touch screen I'm having some specific problems.. On the mouse down event I am starting a DispatcherTimer, when the DispatcherTimer ticks some vital code will be executed. However, the problem is that on MouseUp I am stopping the timer because it is required for the user to hold down until the timer ticks. When using a Touch device the MouseUp event is instantly fired after the MouseDown event even though the finger has not actually been lifted off yet.. How can I circumvent this without altering my code too much?

I have tried handling the Preview event. I have tried copy-pasting helper classes that I have found in similar reported problems. I have tried the "Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled" property. Last thing I remember that I have tried is attaching both the Touch events and the Mouse events and sending them through the same place.(Read that you have to check the 'StylusDevice' property of the MouseEventArgs, but it is always null, even when using the touch screen..) So anyway, I have still not been able to hack it with anything that I have tried..

I dont have all the code of the things I have tried that I explained above, but here is at least what I am sitting with at the moment:

```
protected override void OnPreviewMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
  Log.AddEntry("__________ Dashboard : OnPreviewMouseMove");
  InputMove(e);// my Move handling
}


protected override void OnPreviewMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
  Log.AddEntry("__________ Dashboard : OnPreviewMouseDown");
  InputDown(e); // my Down handling
  e.Handled = true;
}


protected override void OnPreviewMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
  Log.AddEntry("__________ Dashboard : OnPreviewMouseUp");
  InputUp(e); // my Up handling
}
```

Last thing I can provide is a log that I have created under testing. You will be able to see that the Up event is firing shortly after the Down event. 
The following log is created on a Touch Screen. At the beginning of the log I put my finger on the screen and I think a second must have passed before I lifted my finger since the log stopped logging.

```
29.04.2019 15:10:02: __________ Dashboard : OnPreviewMouseMove
29.04.2019 15:10:02: __________ Dashboard : OnPreviewMouseDown
29.04.2019 15:10:02: __________ Dashboard : OnPreviewMouseMove
29.04.2019 15:10:02: __________ Dashboard : TIMER STARTED
29.04.2019 15:10:03: __________ Dashboard : OnPreviewMouseMove
29.04.2019 15:10:03: __________ Dashboard : OnPreviewMouseMove
29.04.2019 15:10:03: __________ Dashboard : OnPreviewMouseMove
29.04.2019 15:10:03: __________ Dashboard : OnPreviewMouseMove
29.04.2019 15:10:03: __________ Dashboard : OnPreviewMouseUp
29.04.2019 15:10:03: __________ Dashboard : OnPreviewMouseMove
29.04.2019 15:10:03: __________ Dashboard : TIMER STOPPED
29.04.2019 15:10:03: __________ Dashboard : OnPreviewMouseDown
29.04.2019 15:10:03: __________ Dashboard : OnPreviewMouseMove
29.04.2019 15:10:03: __________ Dashboard : TIMER STARTED
29.04.2019 15:10:03: __________ Dashboard : OnPreviewMouseUp
29.04.2019 15:10:03: __________ Dashboard : OnPreviewMouseMove
29.04.2019 15:10:03: __________ Dashboard : TIMER STOPPED
29.04.2019 15:10:03: __________ Dashboard : OnPreviewMouseMove
```

The following log is created on using a Mouse (same procedure, notice 3 seconds between Down and Up event. The DispatcherTimer Tick event was correctly fired, unlike when using Touch):

```
29.04.2019 15:15:47: __________ Dashboard : OnPreviewMouseDown
29.04.2019 15:15:47: __________ Dashboard : OnPreviewMouseMove
29.04.2019 15:15:47: __________ Dashboard : TIMER STARTED
29.04.2019 15:15:50: __________ Dashboard : OnPreviewMouseUp
29.04.2019 15:15:50: __________ Dashboard : OnPreviewMouseMove
29.04.2019 15:15:50: __________ Dashboard : TIMER STOPPED
```

Comment: are you using the Touch events?

Comment: @Frenchy No I am not using the Touch events.